# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined in function

Tags: jquery

I Have the following code that works OK

```
$('#btnSort').on("click",
        function () {
            $("#sortorder").css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'z-index': '99',
                'left': $(this).offset().right,
                'top': $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5
            }).slideToggle().delay(1000);
        });
```

I'm trying to detect the size of the browser window so have put the code in a function, but I'm now getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Below is my function

```
var width = $(window).width();
    $.fn.positionFunction = function () {
        if (width < 500) {
            $("#styleList").css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'z-index': '99',
                'left': $(this).offset().right,
                'top': $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5
            }).slideToggle(1000);

        } else {
            $("#styleList").css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'z-index': '99',
                'left': $(this).offset().left, <----------Error
                'top': $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5
            }).slideToggle(1000);
        }
    }
```

and I'm trying to call it using the following:

```
$('#btnStyle').on("click", function() {
        $.fn.positionFunction();
    });
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What if you change `$.fn.positionFunction();` to `$(this).positionFunction()` ?

Comment: `this` will be the `jQuery.fn`. It won't be an element as you seem to be expecting

Comment: Have tried but none work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried swapping (this) for $('#styleList') in all instances?